# Fastest way to remove subsets of lists from a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subset, python-itertools

Suppose I have a list of lists like the one below (the actual list is much longer):

```
fruits = [['apple', 'pear'],
          ['apple', 'pear', 'banana'],
          ['banana', 'pear'],
          ['pear', 'pineapple'],
          ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']]
```

In this case, all the items in the lists `['banana', 'pear']`, `['apple', 'pear']` and `['apple', 'pear', 'banana']` are contained in the list `['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']` (the order of items does not matter), so I would like to remove `['banana', 'pear']`, `['apple', 'pear']`, and `['apple', 'pear', 'banana']` as they are subsets of `['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']`.

My current solution is shown below. I first use `ifilter` and `imap` to create a generator for the supersets that each list might have. Then for those cases that do have supersets, I use `compress` and `imap` to drop them.

```
from itertools import imap, ifilter, compress

supersets = imap(lambda a: list(ifilter(lambda x: len(a) < len(x) and set(a).issubset(x), fruits)), fruits)


new_list = list(compress(fruits, imap(lambda x: 0 if x else 1, supersets)))
new_list
#[['pear', 'pineapple'], ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']]
```

I wonder if there are more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - verifying if one list is a subset of the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other)

Comment: You can start by droping imap and ifilter to use generator expressions/list comprehensions. They work the same way but produce readable code...

Comment: @BrentWashburne It's not exactly a duplicate. As you can see, my current solution does in fact use `issubset()` as suggested by the linked post. My question is more about how to remove lists that are subsets of other lists in a big list.

Comment: @JBernardo: Could you please give an example? Thank you! :)

Comment: @dawg: Sorry, forgot to change the code. `foo` was supposed to be `supersets`. I updated it

Comment: Are all sub-lists guaranteed to be sets themselves, or could you have `[['pear', 'pineapple', 'pear'], ['pineapple', 'pear']]`?

Comment: @dawg works ok for me. There's an extra `from itertools` floating there but that's the only thing I changed. EDIT: well there was until an edit went through. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it is *faster* but this is easier to read (to me anyway):

```
sets={frozenset(e) for e in fruits}  
us=set()
while sets:
    e=sets.pop()
    if any(e.issubset(s) for s in sets) or any(e.issubset(s) for s in us):
        continue
    else:
        us.add(e)
```

---

***Update***

It is fast. Faster still is to use a `for` loop. Check timings:

```
fruits = [['apple', 'pear'],
        ['apple', 'pear', 'banana'],
        ['banana', 'pear'],
        ['pear', 'pineapple'],
        ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']]

from itertools import imap, ifilter, compress    

def f1():              
    sets={frozenset(e) for e in fruits}  
    us=[]
    while sets:
        e=sets.pop()
        if any(e.issubset(s) for s in sets) or any(e.issubset(s) for s in us):
            continue
        else:
            us.append(list(e))   
    return us           

def f2():
    supersets = imap(lambda a: list(ifilter(lambda x: len(a) < len(x) and set(a).issubset(x), fruits)), fruits)
    new_list = list(compress(fruits, imap(lambda x: 0 if x else 1, supersets)))
    return new_list

def f3():
    return filter(lambda f: not any(set(f) < set(g) for g in fruits), fruits)

def f4():              
    sets={frozenset(e) for e in fruits}  
    us=[]
    for e in sets:
        if any(e < s for s in sets):
            continue
        else:
            us.append(list(e))   
    return us              

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit     
    for f in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
        print f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f()", setup="from __main__ import f, fruits"), f()
```

On my machine on Python 2.7:

```
f1 8.09958791733 [['watermelon', 'pear', 'apple', 'banana'], ['pear', 'pineapple']]
f2 15.5085151196 [['pear', 'pineapple'], ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']]
f3 11.9473619461 [['pear', 'pineapple'], ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']]
f4 5.87942910194 [['watermelon', 'pear', 'apple', 'banana'], ['pear', 'pineapple']]
```

Comment: I tried `f1()`, and I got `set()` as the result..mm

Answer (score 7):

```
filter(lambda f: not any(set(f) < set(g) for g in fruits), fruits)
```

Comment: When I tried your code, I got `[['apple', 'pear'], [['apple', 'pear', 'banana'], ['banana', 'pear'], ['pear', 'pineapple'],  ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'watermelon']]`

Comment: There was a mistake in my code. I think that current version should work.

Comment: It worked for me either way you had it - and either way, this is such a Pythonic answer. It makes me happy.

Comment: Weird. In Canopy editor interface, I kept getting an empty list. But when I tried it in the command-line interface, I got the right results! Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted by @lukaszzenko is correct and works for Python 2.

For Python 3, it will give the object. The code below works on Python 3.

```
list (filter(lambda f: not any(set(f) < set(g) for g in fruits), fruits) )
```

Related post in stackoverflow:
[Python list filtering: remove subsets from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318935/python-list-filtering-remove-subsets-from-list-of-lists)

You may also find other ways of doing it in the link below:
[Remove sublists that are present in another sublist](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-sublists-that-are-present-in-another-sublist/)