# How to wrap each item of a list into its proper list

Tags: python, list

How can I turn a list like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

to something like:

```
b = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

I was thinking of using the `map` function, but then what function would I exactly map a to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list filtering: remove subsets from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318935/python-list-filtering-remove-subsets-from-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension are great for this kinda of thing. I simply put each individual item in a list inside the comprehension. Using map for this would be harder to accomplish.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [[i] for i in a]
```

Edit: List comprehensions are a shorthand for writing small pieces of code inside a loop. The "loop over something and create a new list" paradigm is so common that python decided to create specific syntax to handle this usage. Note that there's also dictionary and set comprehensions for similar usage.

Answer (score 2):

Using a comprehension is the easiest way IMO:

```
>>> [[x] for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

You could also use `map` and a `lambda`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: [x], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Comment: thanks! btw what does list comprehension mean?

Comment: It's where you have a generator expression (like `[x] for x in a`) inside `[]` to put a comprehensive set of the generated values into a list.

Answer (score 0):

use zip(a):

zip returns a list of iterables

Comment: `zip` gives you an iterable of tuples, not a list of lists.  If you do `list(zip(a))` you have a list of tuples, but you need to go one step further and do `list(map(list, zip(a)))` to get a list of lists.

Comment: Technically correct, but given the question it would be helpful to explain HOW `zip` accomplishes this is it is (imo) not a standard use of `zip`

Comment: fair enough @Samwise, python isn't really my thing...  just to a quick shot at delineating the list with a native function

Answer (score 0):

What you ask can be done in a single line with a list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b = [[x] for x in a]

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```