# Convert List of Strings to List of Lists using List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried this:

```
l = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
ll = [list(x) for x in l]
print(ll)
```

and I got this

```
[['c', 'a', 't'], ['d', 'o', 'g'], ['f', 'i', 's', 'h']]
```

what I need is

```
[['cat'], ['dog'], ['fish']]
```

Comment: Is your expected output supposed to be the expected printed output? This is not a valid Python object unless you have defined variables `cat` and so on...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Great catch. I went back and added the quotes in my desired output. Thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap each item of a list into its proper list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162762/how-to-wrap-each-item-of-a-list-into-its-proper-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling the `list` constructor (which breaks the string down to its characters) simply:

```
ll = [[x] for x in l]
```

For each iteration over the elements of `l`, this creates a nested list with the single item `x` in it.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
l = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
ll = [[x] for x in l]
print(ll)
```

This converts every element to an array. What you are doing with the `list()` function is converting a word to an array of  *characters*.

Answer (score 4):

just return a list instead of spliting the strings:

```
l = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
ll = [[x] for x in l]
print(ll)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output you are looking for is actually

```
[['cat'], ['dog'], ['fish']]
```

Then the solution, as provided above, is the list comprehension with the square brackets wrapper:

```
l = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
ll = [[x] for x in l]
print(ll)
```

Output:

```
[[cat], [dog], [fish]]
```

*However*, if the output you're looking for the exactly the one you displayed in your post, then you'll need to use a formatted string:

```
l = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
ll = f"[[{'] ['.join(l)}]]"
print(ll)
```

Output:

```
[[cat], [dog], [fish]]
```

Comment: Yes, I did want the quoted strings in the output. Thank you for catching that.